# Laravel loading twice all pages

Tags: laravel, redirect, loading

I'm getting a strange behavior and after hours trying to figure out what might be causing this issue, still can't solve or understand why is this happening.

The project, using Laravel Framework 5.6.39, suddenly is loading every page twice, like a redirect. This happens in all routes, even the ones not using the master page layouts.

Examples: I call myproject.develop/ or myproject.develop/login or myproject.develop/articles and it loads the correct views but twice. It feels like a redirect to the same page or a refresh.

Some of the things I've done and didn't result: clear cache, clear config, clear views, clear routes, disable debugbar, disable clockwork. The behavior is the same.

Thank in advance for any help in trying to solve this issue.

Comment: If you disable javascript in the browser for your site does it still happen? If so, have you added/edited anything before it started happening?

Comment: Thanks Ross, disabling Javascript doesn't work. It keeps the same behavior. That was one of the changes made but even rolling back didn't solve the issue. After your suggestion, I went back and enabled javascript again in Chrome and all works fine now. Weird!!...

Comment: In Chrome if you open the developer console using F12 and open the network tab and check "preserve log" and then go to a page you should be able to see any 30X redirect responses. That should give a hint at what is different. If nothing is different check if there's any rewrite rules or middleware that may cause a redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Ross Wilson suggestion to disable Javascript in the browser (Chrome o Mac OS), first it didn't solve the issue.

Nevertheless all the steps taken as described in my question, and also cleaning any application settings in the Chrome developers console, it wasn't working.

Then, reverting Chrome settings and re-enable Javascript in Chrome, it "magically" worked and this weird behavior disappeared. Just guessing that this might be a Chrome bug (using Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)) while I was thinking anything was wrong with the application—routes, controllers, scripts, etc.—and it wasn't.

So if anyone starts experiencing this issue of pages loading twice, follow the steps and you might probably get lucky and solve the issue.

Thanks Ross!

Answer (score 2):

Icognito mode solved it... so after dumping a bunch of chrome extensions it finally stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted cache from Chrome and the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

Ok, none of the others thing worked for me. This can be kinda obvious, but is good to check if you dont have any "src=''" in your code, this seems to try to make a request to the same url with the src type header. that happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent 4 hours working on this. Was incredibly confused. Incognito or clearing my cache worked. Even experienced it over multiple browsers.

Also not using "Dev Mode" as in npm run dev, also seemed to solve it.